# Printer Issues with HP printer on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, printing

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I'm having issues printing. I have an HP Officejet Pro 8020 and the driver is installed, says it's 'Ready', and has active jobs in the queue.

For some reason when I go to print it just sits in the queue and will not print.The printer is not the issue because I can print from other devices in my home. It is wirelessly connected on WiFi.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Image of printer driver:

Edit: I have installed hplip-gui, then run hp-setup
When I run it, and connect new device with 'Network/Ethernet/wireless Network I always get 'HLIP cannot detect printers in your network'

Apr 1 2023 Issue Solved as seen in comments below.

Comment: Did you run `hp-setup`?

Comment: Can you find the IP address of the printer? Then run `hp-setup` again. Use the advanced button and enter the IP address of the printer. Then it will find the printer. If this works, you will need to reserve that IP address for your printer in your WiFi router, or set up a static IP address for your printer.

Comment: @user68186 Wow, that worked, thank you so much!! 6 Months of headaches always having to use a different device to print are now gone. Appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `hplip-gui`, then run `hp-setup`.

It will download a proprietary plugin and install it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Comment: I did that, however, it now says HPLIP Cannot detect printers on your network.
However, I use my printer wireless with other devices. I've tried turning off my VPN, it doesn't seem to make a difference. Any knowledge past this point as to what to do?